# Partition types for windows 7 installation

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I am planning to reinstall Windows 7 on my PC but I am not sure how to mark the partitions. Specifically I have three HDD's. Two of them for data storing which already have files in them and one more partitioned to 3 parts, one for the Windows installation.

The two drives for data storing are marked as dynamic and one of them is marked also as system.

Now for the other drive all partitions are marked as basic, the windows installation one as boot, active, crash dump and primary partition, the other as logical drive and the other as page file, logical drive.

What would be the optimum management to do for my setup? I am planning to combine the 2 partitions of one drive (C and E) for the windows installation however I am not sure if I should mark them as basic, dynamic, primary, logical and so on, same goes for the other disks for data storing. I am aware of capabilities of each type, however since I had some troubles in the past with hard drive failures I would like to know if there are any recommendations .

Answer (score 0):

The partition that you install your OS in, has to be marked as primary. You cannot boot from a logical partition. Now for the rest. If you want to have 3 more partitions that's fine. You can make all of them primary. But if you want more you have to make the 4th partition an [extended](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_boot_record) one. And create logical partitions under it.